# FaceDetection onLine API in Android

Tags: android

Can any one tell me which is the best way for onLine FaceDetection in Android. Is there any API for the same? If yes, then how we can implement that? Please suggest me for the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Face.com API for the same.

It returns JSON response after facedetection.
First you have to register on Face.com, it will generate your API ID and secret Key.
Then you have to upload your image on the face.com server as:

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(paramFile.getPath());
         System.out.println("The Width="+img.getWidth()+" & Height:"+img.getHeight());
         String str = "";
         if (this.httpclient == null)
          {
             BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
             HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
             this.httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
          }
         this.httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json");
         HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(post.getParams(), "compatibility");
         MultipartEntity multiPart = new MultipartEntity();
         multiPart.addPart("upload", new FileBody(paramFile, "image/jpeg"));
         multiPart.addPart("api_key", new StringBody("5438f02c1f03bbd229e209abfc811cfb"));
         multiPart.addPart("api_secret", new StringBody("6892f15e9721ad0e720a82f8a7d214c9"));
         multiPart.addPart("f_upload", new StringBody(paramFile.getName()));
         multiPart.addPart("detector", new StringBody("Aggressive"));
         multiPart.addPart("attributes", new StringBody("all"));

         post.setEntity(multiPart);
         response = this.httpclient.execute(post);
         HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (responseEntity != null)
              str = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            return (String)str;
```

This will return a response string as JSON, if the face is detected it gives all information about face if not then doen't give any information. You have to parse that JSON and get the result and enjoy........